# Ошибка в компиляции для C# Unity, Полю "CarControll.carRd" нигде не присваивается значение, поэтому оно всегда будет иметь значение null

Tags: c#, unity3d

К сожалению код выдает ошибку, помогите пожалуйста.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class CarControll : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 15f;
    private Rigidbody carRb;

    private void Start()
    {
        carRb.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        carRb.MovePosition(transform.position - transform.forward * speed *Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы присвойте значение т.к. если не сделаете, то `carRb` будет иметь `null` и при `carRb.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` получите ошибку с Null Reference. Типа: `private Rigidbody carRb = new Rigidbody();`

Comment: `carRb = this,GetComponent<Rigidbody>()`

Comment: Ты пытаешься запросить компонент у самого `carRb`, а не `gameObject` к которому привязан `CarControll`.